# How to get all the values of child elements of an xml file. SQL server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Here is how my XML looks like. I am trying to query XML in SQL Server 2008. I want to display all the claims based on ID.

```
<clue xmlns="http://cp.com/rules/client">
    <claim unit_number="1" number="0000007517" id="S1"
           sequence_number="1">
        <scope_of_claim>Full scope</scope_of_claim>
    </claim>
    <claim unit_number="1" number="0000007518" id="S1"
           sequence_number="2">
        <scope_of_claim>Full scope</scope_of_claim>
    </claim>
</clue>
```

My Query :

The  below query gives me the values for the first claim only.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://cp.com/rules/client')
select xmldocument.value('(//claim/@number)[1]','varchar(20)') as ClaimNumber,  
       xmldocument.value('(//claim/scope_of_claim)[1]','varchar(20)') as Scope
       .....
from clue.xml
```

How can i get all the claims?

Comment: What is `clue.xml` and `xmldocument` Do you have a table called `xml` in a schema called `clue` with a column called `xmldocument`?

Comment: Martin thats right. And, xmldocument is of type xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://cp.com/rules/client')
SELECT xmlid,
       ClaimNumber,
       Scope
FROM   clue.xml
       OUTER APPLY 
                  (SELECT 
                     tbl.col.value('(@number)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS ClaimNumber,
                     tbl.col.value('(scope_of_claim)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS Scope
                    FROM   xmldocument.nodes('//claim') AS tbl(col)) x
```